# Perl Range String ID

Tags: string, perl, range

So I have an ID range for pages in a document that I need to loop to compare values. My problem is the ID's are strings and not number so when I try and loop the range with Perl it doesn't work. Here is an example of my range loop, and an example of my data.

```
foreach($begID..$endID){
   print $_;
}
```

A data example would be

```
 $begID = ABC-ABC-00001; 
 $endID = ABC-ABC-00100;
```

My problem is I cannot loop these values. I know I could split the data based on the "-" and get the 00001 and 00100 values, but the problem with that is the data can vary on different files I am working with.

Is there any other way that someone could suggest to go about this?

**UPDATE**

Until I can post my own answer (in another 7 hours due to being under 100 rep) here is what I came up with:

Okay here is what I did as a solution. I can regex out the numbers starting from the end until it hits an alpha character.

```
($start) = $begID =~ m/(\d+)$/;
($end) = $endID =~ m/(\d+)$/;
```

Then create  the loop from there.

Comment: can you provide more example inputs? Are the letters always in range (A-C)? Do they also increase in the loop?

Comment: Here is some more examples as provided below: ABC-001 ABC001. That ABC could be anything, and even possibly contain numbers, like AB123AC123-0001. And no the letters should not increase when I loop the values.

Comment: It could even be ABC1231AB001 for example.

Comment: @NathanStanfordII Please do not add important information in comments. Use the *`edit`* button above and add it to your question. And please use formatting to make your examples distinct from each other, and do not use words like "anything", unless you actually mean "anything", because "anything" includes whitespace, backslash, `\0`, various UTF characters, or weirder.

Comment: @TLP ok sorry for the confusion. What I should have said is ABC could be any alphanumeric character. Also, thanks for the tip on updating my question. Still a newbie here and not sure how everything should be done. Sorry :/

Comment: @NathanStanfordII You should be aware that perl *can* create ranges with alphanumeric characters. Try looping `"ABC001" .. "ABC100"`, or `"A" .. "ABC"` ..for example.

Comment: It's the `-` that's causing issues here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"data can vary" how?

If by having a fixed string prefix + the number, you can split off the prefix:

```
my ($prefix, $start) = ($begID =~ /^(\D+)(\d+)$/;
my ($prefix2, $end) = ($endID =~ /^(\D+)(\d+)$/;
die "Prefixes don't match" unless prefix eq $prefix2;
foreach my $index ($start .. $end) {
    my $id = "prefix$index";
}
```

Comment: Data can vary as the prefix could sometimes contain ABC-ABC-0001 or it could contain ABC-001 or even ABC001. the good thing is the begID and the endID should always be the same prefix.

Comment: After looking at your answer closer I realized I was doing the same thing in the answer I was going to provide. Thanks again!